# XNA Change background colour programmatically

Tags: colors, xna, sprite

Is there a way to change the colour/color of the background programmatically and constantly, for example, I want the beginning colour to be perfectly blue (for example), then every `Update()` call I want the background to slowly change to green, then yellow, then blue etc.... I want the colours to fade in to the next colour and not just suddenly switch.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?  I know there's `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);` but that's obviously not what I want.

Comment: Why is that not obviously what you want? You can clear the background on each draw to a slightly different color. The Color struct allows for customized colors, so you can easily create a fade from one color to another effect that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GraphicsDevice.Clear` is exactly what you want.

All you still need is a way of [interpolating between colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.color.lerp%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx):

```cs
var red = Color.Red;
var green = Color.Green;

// Gives you a color at half the distance between red and green
var color = Color.Lerp(red, green, 0.5f);
```

If you want to go through the whole color palette you could convert the color to [HSL or HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and animate the hue.

Answer (score 1):

@BrianRasmussen is completely correct.  You can vary the clear color every frame.  Use one of the `Color` constructors that takes number values instead of the color enumeration values.

[This one,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195889%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(new Color(byte r, byte g, byte b));
```

[Or this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd231957%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(new Color(float r, float g, float b, float a));
```

And each frame, update your values of `r`, `g`, and `b`.  Easy.